# Best Ways to send message or data to fax machine

Tags: web-applications

I currently am working on a web application that needs to collect data from a form and will take the information and put it in a report format and sent it to a fax machine and print it out.

What is the easiest way to do this. I would like it to act similar to collecting informastion off of a form and then sending an email, but I would like to send it to a fax instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to use a middleware package or service which provides an API. A quick google search came up with [these people](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev).

If you want to manage the modem locally, there is a Windows COM object on some versions of the operating system which can do faxing for you.

Comment: i have used faxmail.com.  you send them an email and they fax it to the indicated number.